# How to implement a Spell Checker for Microsoft Office?

Tags: ms-office, spell-checking

So far I have searched a way to implement a spellchecker for my local language in Microsoft Office: It seems that Microsoft Office uses the Language Packages to provide spell checking for other languages.

Is there an API to implement this Language Packages?

Sorry if this question is repetitive, I have check a previous question about this topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089338/am-planning-to-create-my-local-language-spell-checker-for-office

This question didn't receive good responses, and I should clarify that I am not looking for Word Add-ins that make the role of a spell-checker.

- http://www.lingsoft.fi/read_and_write

This company provide a proofreader, a spellchecker included for windows products.

So can you orient me with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 2010 of Microsoft Office Word to implement you have to make use of Microsoft's Common Speller API (CSAPI), Check [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a92e546e-2ee1-4a8a-961e-7dd0ccb5c626/developing-a-spelling-engine) for more information.

There is a sample source code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1140/Using-the-Microsoft-Common-Spell-API) on how to implement a DLL which provides the spell checking service, and a PDF document describing the CSAPI.

It is not that easy to obtain Microsoft's documentation on how to implement a spell checker because you have to submit a proposal of your project [here](https://members.microsoft.com/omc/welcome.aspx) or contact someone at [Microsoft Ireland](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/default.aspx) (they are the people in charge of the development and maintenance of the spell checking API), if it is approved they will send you the documentation needed.

I should clarify that the CSAPI only provides the means to develop a spell checker for single words and only using VS C++ (No C# or VB), if you want to develop a Grammar Checker o a Thesaurus you have to ask for other APIs.